# jquery get() method access actionresult with parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, parameters, get, actionresult

I have an ActionResult method :

```
public ActionResult GetData(int id)
{
    return Json(CreateCompaniesList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and want to access it with the jQuery get method.

If it is just :

```
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    return Json(CreateCompaniesList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I can access it like :

```
function drawChart() {
    $.get('/Home/GetData', {},
```

How to do the same when there is a parameter in ActionReuslt method?

Answer (score 1):

One way is just to append the parameter:

```
$.get('/Home/GetData/?id=value',
```

Second way:

```
$.get('/Home/GetData/?id=value', {id="value"},
```

Of course `"value"` is a placeholder to the actual id parameter value,
sending a `"value"` string instead of the integer the server expects to get will fail, obviously.

Comment: or is it parameter as null?

Comment: GetData method does not fire

Comment: it seems that the parameter should be of type 'string'

Comment: @yanko, you are taking gdoron's code too literally. what you got was an example. a little simple analysis would lead you to the conclusion that you need to pass an int. other's can only help you so far. the actualy implementation should be yours

Comment: yanko doesn't seem to care any longer. Shame how many visitors don't even have the decency to **accept** the answer... in this case not even a thanks.